# Corda flow exception: net.corda.core.flows.NotaryFlow$Client is not registered

Tags: corda, corda-flow

Scenario: running 2 Corda nodes (say, A and B) that are running within a larger zone. There is 1 notary node in the zone.

I have 2 different flows: the first flow `f1` only runs on node A and only creates transactions that are stored locally (as in, no other nodes are involved). The second flow `f2` also only runs on node A and creates a transaction that modifies the states inserted by flow `f1` (`s1, s2, ...`) by adding an input-output pair to the transaction where the input states are the existing (`s1, s2, ...`) states and the output states are the modified states (`s1', s2', ...`). Flow `f2` also creates an additional output state, therefore we have `Sn` input states and `S(n+1`) output states. The transaction created in flow `f2` is shared with node B.

Flow `f1` runs fine, but as soon as I run flow `f2` I receive the following error in Node A:

`net.corda.core.flows.UnexpectedFlowEndException: net.corda.core.flows.NotaryFlow$Client is not registered`. In the logs of the notary I can see the same error, and when I check the logs for nodeB it says: `net.corda.core.flows.UnexpectedFlowEndException: Counter-flow errored`

I have local tests, using a mock network that is able to run fine. I currently have no clue on how to debug this issue or whether it is a mistake in the flow itself, or something else. I am running version 4.5.8

Below is the code snippet for creating the transaction in flow `f2` (variables have been renamed):

````
val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary)
            .addOutputState(additionalState, CustomContract.ID)
            .addCommand(
                Command(
                    contract,
                    additionalState.participants.map { it.owningKey })
            )
        existingStates.forEach { txBuilder.addInputState(serviceHub.toStateAndRef<CustomState>(it.ref)) }
        existingStatesModified.forEach { txBuilder.addOutputState(it, CustomContract.ID) }





        // Stage 2.
        progressTracker.currentStep = VERIFYING_TRANSACTION
        // Verify that the transaction is valid.
        txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)

        // Stage 3.
        progressTracker.currentStep = SIGNING_TRANSACTION
        // Sign the transaction.
        val partSignedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)

        // Stage 4.
        progressTracker.currentStep = GATHERING_SIGS
        // Send the state to the counterparty, and receive it back with their signature.
        val otherPartySessions = counterParties.map { initiateFlow(it!!) }
        val fullySignedTx =
            subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(partSignedTx, otherPartySessions, GATHERING_SIGS.childProgressTracker()))

        // Stage 5.
        progressTracker.currentStep = FINALISING_TRANSACTION
        // Notarise and record the transaction in both parties' vaults.
        require(insertEvent(insuranceEventState.fullEvent)) { "Unable to insert event data into the triple store." }
        return subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx, otherPartySessions, FINALISING_TRANSACTION.childProgressTracker()))```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was caused by an incorrectly configured notary (which was out of my control).